# What is the problem with my code , I am trying to search in the stack with an internall and external method

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods, stack

Write a method to find the position of a given element in a stack counting from the top of the stack. More precisely,
the method should return 0 if the element occurs on the top, 1 if there is another element on top of it, and so on. If
the element occurs several times, the topmost position should be returned. If the element doesn’t occur at all, -1
must be returned.
You are asked to write this method in two different ways; one way is to implement it internally inside the
ArrayStack class and the other way is to implement it externally in a separate class. Important: At the end
the stack should be returned to the original state (i.e. no elements should be removed and the order of the elements
should not change).

This is the externall class

```
public class Stack{

public static int searchstack(ArrayStack z, int n) { 
          ArrayStack temp = new ArrayStack(z.size());
       int c = 0;
      boolean flag = false;
      while (!z.isEmpty()) {
        if (z.top() == n) {
            flag = true;
            return c;
        }
        if (z.top() != n) {

            temp.push(z.pop());
                c++;
                flag = false;

            }
    }
    if (flag == false) {
        c = -1;
    }
    while (!temp.isEmpty() && !z.isFull()) {
        z.push(temp.pop());
    }
        return c;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayStack z = new ArrayStack(4);
    z.push(3); // first element
    z.push(7);// 2nd
    z.push(8);// 3rd
    z.push(1);// 4th
    z.printStack();
    int n = 3;
    System.out.println("Searching externally for" + " " + n + " " +  searchstack(z, n));
        System.out.println("Searching internally for" +" "+n+" "+ z.searchfor(n)+" "); //THE ERROR IS HERE

}
  }
```

And this is the ArrayClass

```
public class ArrayStack {
  private int[] theStack;
  private int maxSize;
  private int top;

public ArrayStack(int s) {
    maxSize = s;
    theStack = new int[maxSize];
    top = -1;
      }



public void push(int elem) {
    top++;
    theStack[top] = elem;
       }

public int pop() {
    int result = theStack[top];
    top--;
    return result;
       }

public int top() {
    return theStack[top];
       }

public boolean isFull() {
    return (top == (maxSize - 1));
       }

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (top == -1);
       }

public int size() {
    return (top + 1);
       }
      //HERE IS THE METHOD I IMPLEMENTED INTERNALLY AND CALL IT AT THE STACK CLASS
 public int searchfor(int n) {
    for (int i = top; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (theStack[top] == n) {
            return i;
            }
         }
            return -1;
          }

public void printStack() {
    if (top == -1)
        System.out.println("Stack is empty!!\n");
    else {
        System.out.println(theStack[top] + " <- top");
        for (int i = top - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            System.out.println(theStack[i]);
                System.out.println();
               }
               } 
           }
```

The error appearing at the Stack class is at the last line of calling the searchfor method implemented in the Arraystack class , error says that there is no method implemented in Arraystack with the name searchfor (); thiugh I did implement it .whatseems to be the problem ?

Comment: Your searchFor() method within ArrayStack doesn't see the requirement that if a number if found multiple times then the topmost should be returned. You have to iterate through the entire array and keep track of the highest index where it occurs.  The same for your searchStack method. Also, you are altering the original ArrayStack everytime you don't find a value and then subsequently find it. This is because you return before filling it back up again.

Comment: For my assumption of this stack there isn't a number that is found multiple times  , the error appearing states that the method searchfor(); is not defined in ArrayStack class

Comment: @JBNizet could you please help me out with this

Comment: Unfoutunately  not the method name i wrote and calling it in array class are the same Case senstivity

Comment: I noticed that you initially had the method called searchFor but wrote it as searchfor in the comments. Now that you've changed your question from searchFor to searchfor, are you still getting the same error?

Comment: yes ,the same error . Is there another solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bug in your searchStack() implementation. You are losing elements if you find the one you are looking for and it isn't the topmost one.

How to fix your searchStack() method:

- keep popping z until you have an empty ArrayStack. While doing so, add the value to a queue.
- create valIndex and assign it -1.
- Then go through the queue and remove the items from it and adding them to z.  While doing so, check for the *last* occurence of the desired value and save it in valIndex.
- if valIndex equals -1 return it. Else, use following equation to convert it to correct index and return:

  valIndex = (z.size - 1) - valIndex